# node JS firebase post to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase functions and need to make a POST to a PHP page. I have the paid version of Firebase in which Cloud Functions theoretically supports this. The call is happening + not throwing an error, but it also doesn't do what it ought to. I've tried all of the things which are currently commented out, and none of them appear to be doing what I want. I am not attached to any of the solutions, just need the post to actually work.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


const request = require('request');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load();

exports.sendClientData = functions.database.ref('/clients').onWrite((event) => {

  /*
  const original = event.data.val();

  const options = {
    url: "http://test.weblinxteam.com/index.php",
    json: {
      data: {
        submit: {
          name: "new name"
        },
        name: "test"
      },
    }
  }
  request({
    uri: "http://example/index.php",
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      submit: {
        name: "test"
      },
      name: "test"
    }),
  }, function(a, s, d) {
    console.log("response is");
    console.log(a, s, d);
  });
  */

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://example/index.php",
    data: {
      submit: {
        name: "test"
      },
      name: "test"
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log("deed it");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr, status, error);
    }
  });

});
```

EDIT:
I know the exact $.ajax call there works and does what I want, as simply running it in a browser on any site with jquery produces the desired result.

Edit 2:
I get the following response in firebase console from the log when I use the request version, I am not sure how to interpret it. I know it appears cut off, this is the entirety of what appears.

```
5:08:05.111 PM
info    
sendClientData
null IncomingMessage { _readableState: ReadableState { objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 }, length: 0, pipes: null, pipesCount: 0, flowing: true, ended: true, endEmitted: true, reading: false, sync: true, needReadable: false, emittedReadable: false, readableListening: false, resumeScheduled: false, defaultEncoding: 'utf8', ranOut: false, awaitDrain: 0, readingMore: false, decoder: null, encoding: null }, readable: false, domain: null, _events: { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function] ], close: [ [Function], [Function] ], data: [Function], error: [Function] }, _eventsCount: 4, _maxListeners: undefined, socket: Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: null, _parent: null, _host: 'test.weblinxteam.com', _readableState: ReadableState { objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, buffer: [Object], length: 0, pipes: null, pipesCount: 0, flowing: true, ended: false, endEmitted: false, reading: true, sync: false, needReadable: true, emittedReadable: false, readableListening: false, resumeScheduled: false, defaultEncoding: 'utf8', ranOut: false, awaitDrain: 0, readingMore: false, decoder: null, encoding: null }, readable: false, domain: null, _events: { end: [Object], finish: [Function: onSocketFinish], _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd], free: [Function: onFree], close: [Object], agentRemove: [Function: onRemove], drain: [Function: ondrain], error: [Function: socketErrorListener] }, _eventsCount: 8, _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: WritableState { objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, needDrain: false, ending: true, ended: true, finished: true, decodeStrings: false, defaultEncoding: 'utf8', length: 0, writing: false, corked: 0, sync: false, bufferProcessing: false, onwrite: [Function], writecb: null, writelen: 0, bufferedRequest: null, lastBufferedRequest: null, pendingcb: 0, prefinished: true, errorEmitted: false, bufferedRequestCount: 0, corkedRequestsFree: [Object] }, writable: false, allowHalfOpen: false, destroyed: true, _bytesDispatched: 173, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: null, _server: null, parser: null, _httpMessage: ClientRequest { domain: null, _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 5, _maxListeners: undefined, output: [], outputEncodings: [], outputCallbacks: [], outputSize: 0, writable: true, _last: true, upgrading: false, chunkedEncoding: false, shouldKeepAlive: false, useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true, sendDate: false, _removedHeader: [Object], _contentLength: null, _hasBody: true, _trailer: '', finished: true, _headerSent: true, socket: [Circular], connection: [Circular], _header: 'POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\nhost: test.weblinxteam.com\r\ncontent-length: 44\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n', _headers: [Object], _headerNames: [Object], _onPendingData: null, agent: [Object], socketPath: undefined, timeout: undefined, method: 'POST', path: '/index.php', _ended: true, parser: null, res: [Circular] }, read: [Function], _consuming: true, _idleNext: null, _idlePrev: null, _idleTimeout: -1 }, connection: Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: null, _parent: null, _host: 'test.weblinxteam.com', _readableState: ReadableState { objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, buffer: [Object], length: 0, pipes: null, pipesCount: 0, flowing: true, ended: false, endEmitted: false, reading: true, sync: false, needReadable: true, emittedReadable: false, readableListening: false, resumeScheduled: false, defaultEncoding: 'utf8', ranOut: false, awaitDrain: 0, readingMore: false, decoder: null, encoding: null }, readable: false, domain: null, _events: { end: [Object], finish: [Function: onSocketFinish], _socketEnd: [Function: onSoc
 null IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function] ],
     close: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     data: [Function],
     error: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'test.weblinxteam.com',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 173,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: null,
     _server: null,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: [Object],
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\nhost: test.weblinxteam.com\r\ncontent-length: 44\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/index.php',
        _ended: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  connection: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'test.weblinxteam.com',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSoc
```

Edit 3:

Thanks guys for the responses. I'm not sure exactly what the difference was, but this:

`request.post('http://sample.com/index.php', {form:{submit:'value',name:"test"}});`

did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Are you positive that `onWrite` is fired and the handler function is called?

Comment: @ChrisG  Yes, logs appear in the firebase console indicating it has been called and the "invocations" count increases

Comment: I meant adding something like `console.log("onWrite fired");` to the function where you run the ajax call. To make the sure `$.ajax()` is called in the first place.

Comment: You are not properly utilizing Promises for async code here. See [this page of the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).